# How to access handler value globally

Tags: go

I have this simple http server. How can i access the request data to a global variable and use it in any part of the application.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

var data string // Get URL data globally and use it in other part of the  application

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := r.URL.Query().Get("somestring")
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", hello)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mux)
}
```

Comment: Go doesn't have global variables, so your literal request isn't possible. The proper solution (in any language) is to pass the data you need to the place that needs it, rather than relying on global variables.

Comment: That's somewhat misleading. An exported package variable is a global by another name.

Comment: The more troubling thing here is: what happens when two requests come in at the same time? What do you expect to happen? A package variable is by definition shared, and creates a race condition if not a total breakdown of application logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use net/context with http.Handler. for example you have "X-Request-ID" in header, you could define middlware like this:

```
func middleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        ctx := newContextWithRequestID(req.Context(), req)
        next.ServeHTTP(rw, req.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
type key int
const requestIDKey key = 0

func newContextWithRequestID(ctx context.Context, req *http.Request) context.Context {
    reqID := req.Header.Get("X-Request-ID")
    if reqID == "" {
        reqID = generateRandomID()
    }

    return context.WithValue(ctx, requestIDKey, reqID)
}

func requestIDFromContext(ctx context.Context) string {
    return ctx.Value(requestIDKey).(string)
}
```

you could get requestIDKey in any handler with Context object.

```
func handler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    reqID := requestIDFromContext(req.Context())
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Hello request ID %v\n", reqID)
}
```

this is just an example. insted of requestIDKey you could have any data which you should put in Context and read from it with a key.
for more detail information visit [this](https://www.joeshaw.org/revisiting-context-and-http-handler-for-go-17/) blog.